# Error!: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm trying to create a sign up form where a user puts his: username and password into two different textboxes, you click the button, it stores the user and pass in the textboxes within my database.

I currently get this error (UPDATED):

> Error!: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`ctollins_TRTdesign`.`USER`, CONSTRAINT `fk_USER_custID` FOREIGN KEY (`custID`) REFERENCES `CUSTOMER` (`custID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

```html
$con = mysql_connect('localhost','ctollins1','Apples11');
$db = mysql_select_db('ctollins_TRTdesign', $con);


$sql="INSERT INTO USER (userName, userPassword)
VALUES
('$_POST[uname]','$_POST[pass]')";
 
if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error!: ' . mysql_error());
  }
echo "1 new client added";
 
mysql_close($con)
```

Comment: I'm very confused. What are you doing here `"INSERT INTO USER ($userName, $pass)
VALUES
('$_POST[uname]','$_POST[pass]')"`? The also is bad practice because you aren't hashing your user's password and are open to SQL injection (a great pairing).

Comment: @chris85 I'm in first year of schooling for this, so I don't know that much and am still learning. Any advice/fixes would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What is `$row`, did you define that elsewhere? Are you suppose to be using `mysql_*`? The `mysqli_` or `PDO`  drivers are the preferred drivers currently for mysql interaction.

Comment: [RTM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html)! the first brackets describe the columns you want to insert, not the values. (mysql is now trying to find the column `123123`, but since a column cannot have only digits, thats an error)

Comment: `INSERT INTO USER (columnForUserName, columnForPassword)...`

Comment: where did you define $row["userPassword"] ???

Comment: @chris85  I just realized my mistake on that part. The rows were not neccessary. I just changed it to: "INSERT INTO USER (userName, userPassword)  because userName and userPassword are where in the DB i'd like to store them.

Comment: I now get: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`ctollins_TRTdesign`.`USER`, CONSTRAINT `fk_USER_custID` FOREIGN KEY (`custID`) REFERENCES `CUSTOMER` (`custID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

Comment: Update the question with the new error, and DB scheme. http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41132765/edit.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
INSERT INTO USER ($userName, $pass)......
```

in your code. Please use your column name where you store username and password. I mean table column name as follows.

```
INSERT INTO USER (column-name-for-username-from db-table, column-name-for-password-from db-table).........
```

Comment: I tried that, and now i'm getting "Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`ctollins_TRTdesign`.`USER`, CONSTRAINT `fk_USER_custID` FOREIGN KEY (`custID`) REFERENCES `CUSTOMER` (`custID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)"

Comment: Here is the updated code. Sorry I do not know how to structure code in stackoverflow comments, maybe someone can clean this up:

$con = mysql_connect('localhost','ctollins1','Apples11');
$db = mysql_select_db('ctollins_TRTdesign', $con);


$sql="INSERT INTO USER (userName, userPassword)
VALUES
('$_POST[uname]','$_POST[pass]')";
 
if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error!: ' . mysql_error());
  }
echo "1 new client added";
 
mysql_close($con)

Comment: This means from your USER table, the custID referencing to the custID of CUSTOMER table. So while inserting you need to maintain the relationship with valid custID.
According to your comment.

Comment: Ah I see, so in that case I assume I should in some way create a new ID for every customer?

Comment: Yeah because your USER and CUSTOMER table are in relation and cascade on delete too. Take a look at "foreign key constraints" - MySQL/PHP.